# Browser sending 'OPTIONS' request instead of GET/POST in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Browser is sending `OPTIONS` instead of `GET/POST` request in API Request to cross domain.  I'm using Laravel 5.4 for backend and for frontend I'm using Angular 4

I've added Cors in routeMiddleware:

```
return $next($request)
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

**api.php (routes):**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function(){
    Route::post('login', 'ApiController@login');
    Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');
    Route::post('userInfo', 'ApiController@get_user_details');
});
```

What could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 3):

Browser is always sending `OPTIONS` request, This is actually a preflight request which is security measurement. When server understands this request and responds with 200 code, browser sends actual request (with real method GET, POST,...) to a server.

Your server needs to understand how to reply on preflight requests (requests with OPTIONS method).

Here you can find how can this be achieved in nodeJS server

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST", "PUT", "DELETE");

  next();
};
```

Comment: that is if you could edit the server's response to send a suitable CORS response, but many servers you would not have that opportunity - so what would you do in that case - say you were using an angular front end - which is similar to the ques